# list organized into columns not rows

Tags: python, list, rows

I have a list of lists that I am trying to write to columns instead of rows.  My list looks like this:

```
['31 32 31 8', '31 31 32 8', '31 31 31 8', '31 32 31 31']
```

I want it to llok like this:

```
31 31 31 31
32 31 31 32
31 32 31 31
8 8 8 31
```

I can get a nice print in rows like this:

```
with open("text.csv", 'w') as f:
    for x in zip(contents):
        f.write('\t'.join(x)+'\n')
```

What I would like to do is get this data in columns

Comment: What you have there is a list of strings, not a list of lists.

Comment: A useful thing: if you have a list of columns and want a list of rows, you can swap it by doing `zip(*old_list)`. e.g. `zip(*[(1,3,5,7), (2,4,6,8)]) -> [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) for this. Firstly convert your *list of string* to *list of list* using `str.split()`, then iterate over *zip*ed list. Below is the sample code:

```
>>> my_list = ['31 32 31 8', '31 31 32 8', '31 31 31 8', '31 32 31 31']
>>> my_list_list = [s.split() for s in my_list]
>>> for item in zip(*my_list_list):
...     print item
...
('31', '31', '31', '31')
('32', '31', '31', '32')
('31', '32', '31', '31')
('8', '8', '8', '31')
```

Comment: perfect!  Even better without imports

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module to output the data once you've massaged it into shape with `zip()`:

```
import csv

# data is a list of lists    
data = [s.split() for s in ['31 32 31 8', '31 31 32 8', '31 31 31 8', '31 32 31 31']]

with open('text.csv', 'w') as f:    
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerows(zip(*data))
```

This results in a CSV file which uses tab as the delimiter that looks like this:

```
31  31  31  31
32  31  31  32
31  32  31  31
8   8   8   31
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, `numpy` is really good for this kind of stuff. 

If you have 

`test = numpy.array([[31,32,31,8], [31,31,32,8], [31,31,31,8], [31,32,31,31]]`

then you can access the first column by saying
`test[:,0]` which returns `array([31, 31, 31, 31])`